# How to clone files from Github to windows VM using Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to jenkins and I was wondering if you could help me with an example

I'm new to jenkins and I wanted to know if you could help me with an example like I want to clone my repository from git hub in the windows vm on gogle I just think for node does anyone have any examples for windows